# How to convert ndarray audio data to wav file binary data

Tags: python, numpy

### What I want to achieve

I want to convert ndarray audio data to binary data in wav files.
However, I do not want to save the audio data as a wav file and reload it.

### What I don't understand

How to create a wav file binary data (bytearray) from ndarray audio data.
The source code is as follows

```
 def handle(self, data):
        model_input = self.preprocess(data)
        model_output = self.inference(model_input)
        output = self.postprocess(model_output)
        #Now I want to create the binary data (bytearray) of the wav file from the output
        #return Binary data created
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you going to do with the data?  There's no point in worrying about the wave file format if you're not writing it to disk.  If you're just going to do analysis on the waveform, then do analysis on what you have.  If you're going to play it to speaker, then you probably do want a wave file on disk.

Comment: This process is done on the server and I want to transfer the wav file to the client.

Comment: What kind of a client?  If it is an HTTP client, then you'll need it to be a wave file.  I suppose you could use an IOString instead of a disk file.

Comment: Yes, it is an HTTP client.
Could you please tell me how to use IOString?